# Flutter correct DateTime format to compare in where condition for timestamp Cloud Firestore

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I try to use this method to filter my schedule from Cloud Firestore:

```
DateTime _now = DateTime.now();
DateTime _start = DateTime(_now.year, _now.month, _now.day, 0, 0);
DateTime _end = DateTime(_now.year, _now.month, _now.day, 23, 59, 59);


stream: Firestore.instance
           .collection('schedule')
           .where('date', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: _start) 
           .where('date', isLessThanOrEqualTo: _end) 
           .orderBy('date')
           .snapshots(),
```

Results are not filtered.

[Cloud Firestore date format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k86Ah.png)

Comment: Were you able to obtain the functionality?